# Production Flask Server With Gunicorn: Is a global dict thread-safe (even though its not process safe)

Tags: python, flask, thread-safety, global-variables, gunicorn

I am developing an app with flask and I want to have a dict that allows client to upload large files or json data in chunks

My code works perfectly fine in flask debug mode, but I was wondering if I would run into a problem with hash collisions due to Flask's underlying multithreading (when I use it in production with a wsgi server).

In my case, I don't need data to be shared between wsgi processes since the data in the dict is very temporary, but I know that Flask uses multithreading under the hood

My guess is that it is safe because of Python's infamous GIL, but I am not sure

My code:

```py
app = Flask(__name__)

chunk_storage = dict()

@app.route("/chunking", methods=["POST"])
def chunking():
    global chunk_storage
    request_json = request.get_json()
    command = request_json.get("command")
    try:
        if command == "lock":
            u = str(uuid())
            while u in chunk_storage:
                u = str(uuid())
            chunk_storage[u] = []
            return jsonify({"lock": u})
        elif command == "append":
            data_string = request_json.get("data_string")
            lock = request_json.get("lock")
            chunk_storage[lock].append(data_string)
            return jsonify({"write_ok": True})
        elif command == "release":
            lock = request_json.get("lock")
            del chunk_storage[lock]
            return jsonify({"release_ok": True})
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"Unsupported command: {command}")
    except ValueError as e:
        raise e
    except:
        log(str(e))
```